# Stretching the items of an ItemsControl

Tags: wpf, datatemplate, itemscontrol

I'm bulding a small WPF app over here. It's all built strictly with MVVM, using nothing but DataTemplates linked to view model types.

I've seen alot of questions about how to stretch and clip the contents of `ListBox`es so that the items fill its parent. After alot of experimenting I managed to get my head around that but now I find myself in the same scenario with the `ItemsControl` but the same tricks doesn't seem to work.

Here's one of the `DataTemplate`s in use (a simple `TextBox`). Note how I tried setting the `HorizontalAlignment` ...

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:OneOfMyViewModelTypes}">
    <TextBox 
        Text="{Binding Path=Value}"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        />
</DataTemplate>
```

Here's the `ItemsControl` inside a `Grid` ...

```
<Grid Background="Gray">
            <Grid.Margin>
                <Thickness 
                    Left="{StaticResource ConfigurationDefaultMargin}" 
                    Right="{StaticResource ConfigurationDefaultMargin}" 
                    Bottom="{StaticResource ConfigurationDefaultMargin}" 
                    Top="{StaticResource ConfigurationDefaultMargin}" 
                    />
            </Grid.Margin>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="_key" Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="_value" Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <ItemsControl 
                Background="DimGray" 
                Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Configuration, Mode=OneWay}" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                >
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="_key"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="_value"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock
                                Style="{StaticResource ExtensionConfigurationLabel}"
                                Grid.Column="0"
                                Margin="5,5,5,0"
                                Text="{Binding Path=Caption}" 
                                />
                            <ContentPresenter 
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                Margin="5,5,5,0"
                                Content="{Binding}" 
                                />
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </Grid>
```

I've used colors to see how the controls sizes. The `Grid` is gray and the `ItemsControl` is dark gray.

This is the result ...

[image: This is the result]

As you can see from the colors the containing `Grid` stretches while the `ItemsControl` does not. I did set its `HorizontalAlignment` property to `Stretch` but it seems it has no effect. Is there anything else I need do?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two columns in your main (outer) grid, yet you use only the first column.
The second column uses all the remaining space.

Comment: Lester: I was under the misconception that I needed that outer Grid to be able to use shared size scope for its columns. As you can see I do tie the two elements of each item to one of the two columns. Apparently I can use this feature without an aouter grid and that made the ItemsControl stretch as expected. But the items (the text box of the DataTemplate) still auto sizes to its own content.